# Vaulted kitchen ceiling but now have moisture between roof and insulation. Possible cause and remedy?

Tags: ceiling, roof, ventilation, moisture, condensation

We're re-doing our kitchen and decided to vault the ceiling. Previously, above the ceiling there was a good amount of attic space but now the insulation is right up against the inside of the roof, and the sheetrock on top of that.

The roof is fine. We only bought the house back in June and the inspector said the roof was in good shape from what they could tell, plus if it was leaking we would have noticed it when the kitchen was ripped down to the studs.

I have some people installing the lighting and they noticed condensation on the inside of the roof boards and on that insulation that butts up against it.

The electrician is also a home inspector and believes that when the cold air that's coming in from my soffits meets the warm air coming up from inside the house, it's creating that condensation.

I asked the contractor that's doing the work and he doesn't think the soffits are vented because when the kitchen was apart, you couldn't see daylight out of them. For that reason, he's thinking that we should remove the soffits and drill some holes so that they can vent properly.

Any thoughts or possibly remedies here would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you failed to provide any venting space between the insulation and the roof sheathing, merely adding soffit vents won't fix this. Is there any ridge venting? This is a VERY standard detail, so whoever made that choice did zero research, and lacks experience.

Comment: @Ecnerwal no, the installer did not leave any space between the insulation and the roof and did not install a ridge vent. Do you think that installing a ridge vent and soffit vents will be enough, or do we need to remove the ceiling and also add some type of space between the insulation and roof?

Comment: Cardboard box full of stuff flows no air. Poke a hole in each end, very little air flows through. You'll want _some_ sort of air flow gap to keep the roof cool. Of course, you can go with a hot roof, but that comes with other issues.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. You now know you need proper attic ventilation. What are you asking us?

Comment: Sounds like there is no ventilation or vapor barrier so warm humid air is getting past the insulation and condensing on the inside of the cold roof. It's a serious issue and should have been addressed when the vaulting was done in the first place.

Comment: What are your ground snow loads like?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a 1" gap between the roof sheathing and the insulation. See [806.3 of the IRC](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.3). From [806.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.1), "cross ventilation" means that there is a vent at both ends of every rafter cavity. Technically, I think that soffit vents with some work around at the ridge satisfies the requirement, where ridge venting could be unnecessary.