# Is it okay to use 2x4 R-13 insulation for garage rafters?

Tags: insulation, garage

I'm working on insulating my bare bones garage in Southern California so the climate is mild. Just trying to not have R-0.

I insulated the walls with R-13 and planned on insulating the ceiling as well. I don't want to create a ceiling on the joist though and I would rather keep it as a cathedral ceiling. My rafters though are only 2x4s which is making it hard for me to find a R-38 insulation for the ceiling which is recommended.

Would it be okay if I just stuck with R-13 insulation for the ceiling rafters instead but also use a layer of radiant barrier? I'm looking to just improve the garage, I'm not living in it so it doesn't need to be perfect. Just not sure if that is the right choice/waste of money.

The ceiling joist are 2x4s spaced 24 inches apart, so I also looked at R-30 but that is still 9.25" thick.

[image: Rafters]

Comment: Depending on where you are, a garage may not require insulation or may not require tbe same level of insulation as the rest of the house. In which case, you can do what you want, depending on cost, diffculty and warmth required.

Comment: Those are roof rafters.  Insulating roof decks is a different animal.  Most roof decks should have ventilation from the bottom going to the top.  I would think about placing supports for the insulation on the bottom of the ties(going wall to wall).  Can be tight string/wire to 1x4s nailed on the bottom.

Comment: I am not wanting to add the insulation to the rafters ties though. I'll do some more research then I guess about how I could insulate the roof deck.

Comment: Per @crip659's good comment, the roof deck needs to be ventilated. Insulation will hold heat during summer and shorten the life of shingles without it (if sunlight hits the shingles).

Comment: Look up warm roofs.  They are roofs with insulation on the roof deck.  Your roof might not be made for it.  I do not have enough information about them except the name.

Comment: Got it. Very helpful. Thanks you guys! Did not know that the roof needs to be vented. I'll do some more research on alternative options or if I just need to break down and insulate the rafters.

Comment: Is the garage heated? Cooled?  Are you at high altitude?  What is your goal, to insulate what from what?  Southern California can mean almost anything.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/288506/vaulted-kitchen-ceiling-but-now-have-moisture-between-roof-and-insulation-possi/288542#288542 for the relevant links into the International Residential Code.

Answer (score 2):

For a cathedral ceiling insulation scenario, you would normally want a bit *less* than 3.5 inches of insulation in a 3.5" deep rafter bay, with ridge and soffit vents so that the space between the roof deck and the insulation is vented - or you would fur the rafters down a bit more to permit ventilation with 3.5 inches (or more) of insulation, or use insulation offering more insulation value in less space, such as R15-18 3" foam boards, or 2" foam (or things like ridgedized rockwool "boards") between rafters and additional foam or "boards" (perhaps foil faced) under (towards the inside of the building) the rafters and other insulation.

How this plays out specifically in your climate, I don't know, but that's the usual way it's done, in general.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a 1" minimum gap between the underside of the subroof and the insulation. See [R806.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.3) from the IRC. From [R806.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.1), "cross ventilation" means that there is a vent at both ends of every rafter cavity. Soffit vents with some work around at the ridge satisfy the requirement. Ridge venting also works, but I doubt that you want to tear into the roof.

Running insulation perpendicular to the rafters is probably a better idea. A grid of hangers connected by galvanized wire or rope is my instinct to keep the insulation up there.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be okay if I just stuck with R-13 insulation for the ceiling rafters instead but also use a layer of radiant barrier?

#### Yes

As you've noted, you're just trying to avoid the temperature extremes, not trying to make it a bedroom, so *some* insulation will be just fine. Just make sure that your radiant barrier is properly fire rated and won't emit all sorts of toxic smoke in a fire.

Of course, if you're expecting any sort of inspection of this work afterwards, then that probably will *not* meet code and will probably fail the inspection, so really it's a "qualified Yes".

---

Addressing the *sorta* asked question of how do I get more insulation in there:

Without looking up exact insulation thickness, but just working off the R-30 = 9.5" of depth (as noted in the OP), I'd propose this:

Needs:

1. You need 9.5" of depth for the R-30 insulation, plus ~1" of depth for soffit-ridge ventilation, for a total depth of 10.5".
2. The existing 2x4 is 3.5" tall which means you need an additional 7" of depth. A 2x8 is 7.5" tall, so that meets our needs (4.5 + 7.5 = 11" which is the smallest standard dimensional lumber way of getting to 10" without cutting).

Resolution:

1. Purchase two 2x8s for each pair of existing rafters.
2. Cut the 2x8s to length & cut the proper angles on each end.
3. Drill several pocket holes into each of the 2x8s along the top edge.
4. Use pocket hole screws to attach the 2x8s to the bottom of the 2x4 rafters.

   - Since the 2x4s are the structure holding up the roof, the 2x8s are, therefore, *not* structural and pocket hole screws will be sufficient to keep the 2x8s from falling on the heads of those below.
5. Put your R-30 insulation into the newly created 11" tall space, leaving a 1.5" gap at the top for ventilation.

---

Yes, this is overkill, but, IMHO, so is R-30 insulation in a garage roof in SoCal when the goal it to "just make the environment nicer", as opposed to making it fully conditioned living space.

I live in Central Indiana where it's (likely) significantly colder than your SoCal location (I know, there are mountains in Southern California, but you haven't told us where, exactly, so I'm assuming beach side ;), I've got 2x8 rafters in my new shop, and I'm going to fit as much insulation up there as I can get in my 6.5" of available space and I'll call it good.

YMMV...